# How to remove "No Internet" from wifi menu?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Since I updated my Windows 10 to version 1909, I noticed that after I connect to internet using USB tethering, this block gets added on top of the WiFi menu and I cant find a way to remove it.

[image]

If I click on this "No Internet", it opens this page in settings:
[image]

And then if I click on the yellow area, it just closes the window.

Anyone using Win 10 v 1909 please try using USB tethering to connect to internet and let me know if you also get the same issue.

Comment: Run cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run both:
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   followed by SFC /SCANNOW.   When done, restart and test.

Comment: This link may help you answer this question: http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1074-how-to-mange-network-connectivity/

Comment: Please provide the output of `ipconfig /all`. And maybe also the interface list from `route print`.